# Dictionary of List to List of KeyValuePair using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to find the most "elegant" way to deal with the transformation between two collections using LINQ. The source container type is `Dictionary<int, List<string>>` and I need to convert it to `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`. Basically I need to duplicate the key in the dictionary for every element in its corresponding list into a flattened list. Below shows my 2 attempts to solve the issue.

```cs
        Dictionary<int, List<string>> source = new() {
            {100, new() {"a", "b", "c"}}
        };
        
        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> target = new();
        
        // Solution 1
        foreach (var (score, terms) in source)
        {
            foreach (var term in terms)
            {
                target.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(score.ToString(), term));
            }
        }
            
        // Solution 2
        target = source.SelectMany(kvp =>
        {
            var(score, terms) = kvp;
            return terms.Select(t => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(score.ToString(), t));
        }).ToList();
```

Runnable sample [here on .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yVccEa).

I'm using .NET Core 5 and C# 9 in a console application.

Both of these work, I think, but I want to see if I can make this cleaner. It's pretty difficult to find out how to use LINQ to solve complex transformations like this. One thing I tried to do was "deconstruct" the KeyValuePair in `SelectMany()`, like:

```
source.SelectMany((score, terms) => ...)
```

But this didn't work. I'm not sure if there's a way to make that kind of deconstruction possible. Little things like this I think could go a long way to making this cleaner.

Comment: Other than calling `ToString()` just once on the score, there's not much room for making this cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe

```
var results = source
   .SelectMany(x => x.Value
      .Select(y => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x.Key.ToString(), y)))
   .ToList();
```

Or if you are happy with Value Tuples (which have a few benefits)

```
var results = source
   .SelectMany(x => x.Value
      .Select(y => (x.Key.ToString(), y)))
   .ToList();
```

Comment: ohhh I never knew I could do `List<(string, string)>`! What are the benefits here?

Comment: @void.pointer It's a list of value tuple.

Comment: @void.pointer Value Tuples are value types, they have a special C# syntax including deconstruction, they are immutable, the data members are fields, and they have a certain amount of equality, ie you can use `==` and `!=`. On the down side, they can be boxed, and you cant use them for ORMs ect

Comment: I intend to use this list as part of a DTO that represents a REST API response object. I assume that a library like Flurl can deserialize JSON data into a `List<(string, string)>`. This is something I have yet to test. Thank you for the info.

Comment: @void.pointer some serializers can deal with tuples, however it depends on what you want for the output if they can it will be something like this `[{"Item1":"100","Item2":"a"},{"Item1":"100","Item2":"b"},{"Item1":"100","Item2":"c"}]` which may not be what you want, So in this regard `KeyValuePair` might be better

Answer (score 3):

If you want to pattern match it in a single expression ("that kind of deconstruction"), you can abuse (?) the switch expression:

```
target = source.SelectMany(kvp => kvp switch { var (score, terms) =>
    terms.Select(t => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(score.ToString(), t))
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [overload of SelectMany that has a parameter resultSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_SelectMany__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1___System_Func___0___1___2__).

```
var results = source.SelectMany(sourceItem => sourceItem.Value,

// parameter resultSelector:
(sourceItem, listItem) => ...
```

In baby steps:
Source **is** a sequence of `KeyValuePair<int, List<string>>`. So every `sourceItem` is one `KeyValuePair<int, List<string>>`. `sourceItem.Value` is the `List<string>` that belongs to the int `sourceItem.Key`. In the parameter resultSelector you get a combination of the complete sourceItem, with one item from the list:

```
(sourceItem, listItem) =>
```

So if your source is:

```
{ 1, {"A", "B"} }
{ 2, {"C", "D" "E"} }
{ 3, empty list }
```

You get:

```
( { 1, {"A", "B"} }, "A")
( { 1, {"A", "B"} }, "B")
( { 2, {"C", "D" "E"} }, "C")
( { 2, {"C", "D" "E"} }, "D")
( { 2, {"C", "D" "E"} }, "E")
```

No items for 3, the list is empty

Now, from every `sourceItem` you want `sourceItem.Key.ToString()`, from every `listItem` you want the complete `listItem`. So your SelectMany will be:

```
var results = source.SelectMany(sourceItem => sourceItem.Value,

    (sourceItem, listItem) => new KeyValuePair<string, string> 
         (sourceItem.Key.ToString, listItem))
.ToList();
```